# How to use moc in a qmake project that doesn't use Qt modules?

Tags: qt, qmake, moc

I have a qmake project that includes the needed Qt source files directly, thus I don't need to link with any Qt libraries:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG -= qt
```

Yet the removal of Qt support also forces qmake not to process any headers with moc. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
CONFIG += moc
```

This causes the `mkspecs/features/moc.prf` to be included by qmake, adding moc to its repertoire.